# VueJS navigate to child component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a button in a component that onclick will navigate to its child component.

Button code

```
<button class="summary" @click="navigateToSummary">
        <span>Summary</span>
</button>

methods:{
  navigateToSummary() {
      return this.$router.push({
        name: 'PortfolioSummary',
        params: { coinId: this.coinSummary.coinId },
      });
    },
}
```

Router code

```
  {
      name: 'AppPortfolio',
      path: '/portfolio',
      component: AppPortfolio,
      children: [
        {
          name: 'PortfolioSummary',
          path: ':coinId',
          component: PortfolioSummary,
          props: true,
        },
      ],
    },
```

On clicking the button, the url updates in the browser, but it doesnt navigate to the child component.
What am I meant to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AppPortfolio` view requires it's own `<router-view>` where `PortfolioSummary` will be rendered.

Basically when you use nested child routes in this manner they require a `router-view` inside a `router-view` to settle your 2 tree deep setup, a 3 for deep tree example will requires 3 nested `router-views`, so on and so fourth.

- App.vue

  `<router-view>`

  - AppPortfolio

    `<router-view>`

    - PortfolioSummary